# Apply boolean mask only to indexed portion of a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, mask

I have a dataframe with some columns:

```
>>> np.random.seed(0xFEE7)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randint(10, size=10), 
                       'B': np.random.randint(10, size=10),
                       'C': np.random.choice(['A', 'B'], size=10)})
>>> df
   A  B  C
0  0  0  B
1  4  0  B
2  6  6  A
3  8  3  B
4  0  2  A
5  8  4  A
6  4  1  B
7  8  7  A
8  4  4  A
9  1  1  A
```

I also have a boolean series that matches part of the index of `df`:

```
>>> g = df.groupby('C').get_group('A')
>>> ser = g['B'] > 5
>>> ser
2     True
4    False
5    False
7     True
8    False
9    False
Name: B, dtype: bool
```

I'd like to be able to use `ser` to set or extract data from `df`. For example:

```
>>> df.loc[ser, 'A'] -= 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\jfoxrabinovitz\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1762, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "C:\Users\jfoxrabinovitz\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1289, in _getitem_tuple
    retval = getattr(retval, self.name)._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
  File "C:\Users\jfoxrabinovitz\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1914, in _getitem_axis
    return self._getbool_axis(key, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Users\jfoxrabinovitz\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1782, in _getbool_axis
    key = check_bool_indexer(labels, key)
  File "C:\Users\jfoxrabinovitz\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2317, in check_bool_indexer
    raise IndexingError(
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

The error makes sense since `ser` is not the same length as `df`. How do I tell the dataframe to update the rows that match the index of `ser` and are set to `True`?

Specifically, I am looking to modify entries at indices 2 and 7 only:

```
>>> df   # after modification
   A  B  C
0  0  0  B
1  4  0  B
2  3  6  A
3  8  3  B
4  0  2  A
5  8  4  A
6  4  1  B
7  5  7  A
8  4  4  A
9  1  1  A
```

Comment: you may need `df.loc[ser[ser].index,'A']` to assign the values not the entire `ser.index` since other values are false, unsure of the expected - hence commenting :-)

Comment: @anky. Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the question, and am looking forward to your answer, since your comment is exactly what I want.

Comment: It's difficult for me to imagine a scenario where the above Series couldn't be created based on the entire DataFrame in the first place to get a like-indexed Boolean Series. I.e. the above is equivalent to the mask `df.C.eq('A') & df.B.gt(5)`. Further, if you have a duplicated index using `ser` can be problematic.

Comment: @ALollz. Please write that as an answer. I like nothing more than to be XY'd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the index of `ser` doesnot match with the original dataframe, you get that error.

You can solve it 2 ways:

either use `series.reindex` with a `fill_value` of `False` (boolean) and then use `loc` so the indexes are aligned.

```
df.loc[ser.reindex(df.index,fill_value=False),'A'] = ... #setvalue
```

Or you can boolean index the `ser` series so it returns only the `True` values and gran the index which you can use with `loc`:

```
df.loc[ser[ser].index,'A'] = ... #setvalue
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could just add index to `ser` inside the `loc` since both come from a common index.

```
df.loc[ser.index, 'A'] -= 3
```

As commented by @Shubham Sharma, the OP required to filter only the `True` values. This approach get all indexes wih `'A'`.

@anky provided a way for that as:

```
df.loc[ser[ser].index, 'A'] -= 3
```

Comment: Clever idea +1 But you also need to filter the index to include only `True` values otherwise this would update all the values. Something like `df.loc[ser[ser].index, 'A'] -= 3` should work

Comment: `ser[ser].index` might do it